# How to find the solution of this partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to solve

$$ \Delta \sigma + \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \sigma  \partial^\mu \sigma = \frac{3}{2} e^{-2\sigma} \partial_\mu h 
 \partial^\mu h $$

where $\sigma$ and $h$ are fields, and m and n are constants. This equation and its solution $\sigma = m ~ln h$

are given by Equ. (21) and (23) in : [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0266.pdf)

So any help how this solution has been reached?

Comment: What is the metric tensor used in the index-raising for the Einstein summation?

Comment: $\eta_{\mu\nu}=(-1,1,1,1 ) $ @LutzLehmann

Comment: @user619894. That's right.

Comment: Are they sure those coefficients are right? Just plugging in $\sigma = \ln h$ as they suggest and simplifying gives $2\partial_\mu h\partial^\mu h/h^2 = 0$ by my calculation. Note that the $\Delta h$ term drops out because $h$ was chosen to have $\Delta h = 0$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog. Hi, can you address your calculations, what will be the $\sigma$ solution accordingly?